# how to change java -version on windows to show Java 1.9

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have java 1.9 installed on my machine. I can see it in installed programs. But when i type java -version on command prompt it still shows 1.8. How can i change it ?

Comment: So when you check the version, it's 1.9. What do you want to change it to?

Comment: Don't quite get the question? If You installed 1.9, to what version do You expect this should change? Maybe You meant 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant 1.8

Windows and Linux allow multiple JRE to be installed. They have different mechanisms for determining which JRE is used by default. Basically, it comes down to your system path.

Comment: Yes 1.8 i updated my question. Java 9 is installed on my machine. I have set 1.9 in environment variable. But still i see java 1.8 when i run java -version command